# VB script wscript doesn't want to launch

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\Games\SV\Data\R\Launcher.exe", 0, False
```

But when I launch the script it says:

```
Error:
Line: 1
Position: 1
```

I can't figure out what the problem is.
Someone knows how to fix this?

Thanks, Android

Comment: How do you launch your script?

Comment: is it the system cannot find the path specified error??

Comment: You get an error with no error number?

Answer (score 1):

`Line 1, Position 1` seems like to me a compilation error due to script file encoding.
Make sure that the script file is encoded in ANSI or Unicode (Little Endian).

You can save your script files as ANSI or Unicode encoded using Windows Notepad through `File > Save As`. You'll see encoding options in the Save As dialog.